# Android reCAPTCHA: Verifying the user's response: all the functions must be called client-side! Can I use my backend however?

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, recaptcha

I want to verify the reCAPTCHA of my Android user. So I'm reading this documentation: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify:

> For Android library users, you can call the SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResult.**getTokenResult**() method to get response token if the status returns successful.

In the manual of this function, the following description is written about `getTokenResult` (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResult.html#getTokenResult()):

> Gets the reCAPTCHA user response token, which must be validated by calling the **siteverify** method described in Verify the user's response.

The manual of the `siteverify` function describes the following (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient.html#verifyWithRecaptcha(java.lang.String)):

> Provides user attestation with reCAPTCHA.
>
> If reCAPTCHA is confident that this is a real user on a real device it will return a token with no challenge. Otherwise it will provide a visual/audio challenge to attest the humanness of the user before returning a token.

## My question

I want to use my backend server (Cloud Functions) to verify the reCAPTCHA. However, according to the Android documentation, all the above functions seem to be put client-side. Indeed, `siteverify` should be called with the token got with `getTokenResult`, and both seem to be part of the Android SecureNET ReCAPTCHA Android API...

However, I think that using Cloud Functions would be more secure! Can I use my backend however?

### Edit: back-end call to siteverify in Cloud Functions

```
exports.verifyRecaptcha = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const user_response_token = request.query.user_response_token;
    if(user_response_token == '') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with an adequat user response token.');
    }
    
    const remote_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    const secret = null;
    request.post({url: remote_url, form:{secret: secret, response: user_response_token}}, function(error, response, body) {
        if(error) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error);
        }

        if(!response.statusCode != 200) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Something went wrong. Status code: ' + response.statusCode + '.');
        }

        if(!body.success) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unable to verify this captcha.');
        }

        return response;    
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the token returned from `getTokenResult()`, send it to your backend, and have your backend call the web API version of [`siteverify`](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api_request):

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
```

Comment: Please can you tell me if my backend call to `siteverify` is correct?:) (code inserted in my question)

Comment: I don't know. It looks OK. Does it work? I use URL params instead. And I don't know where that `return response;` is supposed to go.